# in depth coverage of WebMatrix?

Tags: webmatrix

Hi guys
I'm curious if there is any in-depth articles/eBooks/ that cover WebMatrix technology. I was lookin @ MSDN video tutorials so far, but I would like to dig deeper, so looking for in-depth coverage of technology. If you can recommend one, or provide links I would be greatly appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only book that's currently shipping I am aware of is  [Web Development 101 using Webmatrix](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004I6D676).  It's an eBook for Kindle.  I sometimes run the Kindle software on my computer when developing side by side with the development environment.  This is a basic introduction by Laurence Moroney.  He also has a more comprehensive book [Introducing Microsoft WebMatrix](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0790145308870/) due May 20, 2011.

You should read all of Mike's  [Web Matrix blog entries](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Category/28).   Mike has a book in the works, but it's not shipping yet.

[Getting Started with WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/1-getting-started-with-webmatrix-and-asp-net-web-pages) is pretty helpful from the Microsoft ASP site.

The [How To's for WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/category/how-to) from the Microsoft Site are a basic introduction.

[SimpleMembership for WebPages](http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx) is an introduction to how to add authentication, log-in, membership to a website.  It's from Matthew Osborn and he has additional [Webmatrix Entries](http://blog.osbornm.com/category/31.aspx)

[Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) is a cheat sheet by Phil Haack.

[ScottGu's WebMatrix posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/search.aspx?q=webMatrix&o=Relevance) should be read.

It's worth reading [Thoughts on WebMatrix](http://wekeroad.com/2011/01/13/someone-hit-their-head/) by Rob Conery.  Rob has created a micro-ORM (he calls it Data Access Happyness) called [Massive](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive) which originally was just for WebMatrix, but I believe has expanded beyond it.

Speaking of Rob Conery, it's a good podcast worthy of listening to [HanselMinutes podcast on WebMatrix](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanseminutesPodcast249OnWebMatrixWithRobConery.aspx) with Scott Hanselman.  They developed [This Developer's Life](http://thisdeveloperslife.com/) in WebMatrix.

[Erik Reitan's WebMatrix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikreitan/archive/tags/webmatrix/) blog entries are helpful, especially about Helpers.

[Chris Love's WebMatrix entries](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/tags/WebMatrix/default.aspx) are helpful, especially for using jQuery Templates.

Comment: Thanx for reply Knox! and thanx for all the provided links, seems we have to wait till books, that cover WebMatrix technology in-depth, will be published.